# Python pandas merge command doesn't work inside the code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to do the following:

```
>>>df = pd.read_table('file1.txt')
>>> df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv',quotechar="'")
>>> df.columns
Index(['ID', 'Tweet', 'Intensity Score'], dtype='object')
df2.columns
Index(['ID', 'Tweet'],
      dtype='object')
>>>pd.merge(df, df2, on='ID')
```

The last command (pd.merge) works fine when I try it on the terminal, however when I put the same code inside the foo.py and run that foo.py I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 208, in <module>
    main()
    df_merged_trn=pd.merge(df,df2,on='ID')
  File "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 60, in merge
    validate=validate)
  File "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 550, in __init__
    self.join_names) = self._get_merge_keys()
  File "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 856, in _get_merge_keys
    rk, stacklevel=stacklevel))
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1379, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'ID'
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: 'ID' is not in your dataframe as a column or index

Comment: This kind of `KeyError` suggests that the `df` and `df2` dataframes that you're trying to merge do not both have a column with key `'ID'`. Are you certain that the dataframes have the content that you think they have? Add a `print` statement for both dataframes just before the line that is triggering the `KeyError`, and check the output.